# Java проблема парсинга даты

Tags: java, парсер, дата, jsoup

Решаю задачу парсинга вакансий с сайта HeadeHunter при помощи jsoup и пытаюсь парсить дату, но получаю ошибку:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1 апреля 2018"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
at ru.skilanov.io.jobsparser.HtmlParser.convertDate(HtmlParser.java:116)
at ru.skilanov.io.jobsparser.HtmlParser.getDate(HtmlParser.java:105)
at ru.skilanov.io.jobsparser.HtmlParser.createJob(HtmlParser.java:64)
at ru.skilanov.io.jobsparser.HtmlParser.getAllJobs(HtmlParser.java:53)
at ru.skilanov.io.jobsparser.HtmlParser.main(HtmlParser.java:45)
```

Код метода конвертации строки в дату:

```
private Date convertDate(String date){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String year = String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    String str = String.format("%s %s", date, year);
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMMM yyyy", new Locale("ru", "RU"));
    try {
        return format.parse(str);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Код метода парсинга даты:

```
    private Date getDate(Element element){
    String date = element.select(DATE_QUERY).text();
    return convertDate(date);
}
```

**UPDATE** Проблема решена, входящую строку date метода convertDate нужно было разбить на строки.

Метод convertDate(исправленный):

```
    private Date convertDate(String date) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String year = String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    String str = String.format("%s %s %s", getDay(date), getMonth(date), year);
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMMM yyyy");
    try {
        return format.parse(str);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Метод getDay:

```
    private String getDay(String date) {
    return date.split("[\\u00A0\\s]+")[0];
}
```

Метод getMonth

```
    private String getMonth(String date) {
    return date.split("[\\u00A0\\s]+")[1];
}
```

Comment: начиная с [java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) можно сделать `date.replaceAll( "\\h+", " " )` - заменить подряд идущие горизонтальные пробельные символы (коды см. в документации) на один обычный пробел

Comment: Спасибо, попробую Ваш вариант.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Решение**

Метод convertDate(исправленный):

```
private Date convertDate(String date) {
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
String year = String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
String str = String.format("%s %s %s", getDay(date), getMonth(date), year);
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMMM yyyy");
try {
    return format.parse(str);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
```

}
Метод getDay:

```
private String getDay(String date) {
return date.split("[\\u00A0\\s]+")[0];
```

}
Метод getMonth

```
private String getMonth(String date) {
return date.split("[\\u00A0\\s]+")[1];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

в этом вопросе обсуждалась обратная проблема -
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642720/proper-russian-month-string-translation-java)

здесь упоминают установку своих текстовых констант для парсинга месяцев

```
Locale russian = new Locale("ru");
String[] newMonths = {
  "января", "февраля", "марта", "апреля", "мая", "июня", 
  "июля", "августа", "сентября", "октября", "ноября", "декабря"};
DateFormatSymbols dfs = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance(russian);
dfs.setMonths(newMonths);
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG, russian);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = (SimpleDateFormat) df;
sdf.setDateFormatSymbols(dfs);
```